# jQuery: reverse string slice function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple code that will replace the characters in a string with `'*'` and only displays the last 4 characters of the string. Example:

```
string = 424242424242
```

Should become:

```
********4242
```

The code that does that is this:

```
var str = $('.cc').val();

var trailingCharsIntactCount = 4;
str = new Array(str.length - trailingCharsIntactCount + 1).join('*') + str.slice( -trailingCharsIntactCount);

$('.cc').val(str);
```

Now, I need to reverse that when the users focus on an input field.
This is a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/s66k9x1s/1/

Basically, I need to show/hide the input's value the same way I demonstrated in my fiddle.

Could someone please advice on how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can't really reverse it. You need to save the original value somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string replacement cannot be reversed from thin air,
you need to save the original value somewhere. 
You could use jQuery's [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/), for example.
Store the original value with `.data('value', str)`,
and when the field receives the focus,
restore it from `.data('value')`.

```
function getMaskedValue(str) {
  var trailingCharsIntactCount = 4;
  return new Array(str.length - trailingCharsIntactCount + 1).join('*') + str.slice(-trailingCharsIntactCount);
}

var $cc = $('.cc');
var str = $cc.val();
$cc.data('value', str);

$cc
  .val(getMaskedValue(str));
  .focus(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).data('value'));
  });
```

And as @aaron pointed out,
after focus is lost, you also want to restore the masked value:

```
$cc
  .focus(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).data('value'));
  })
  .blur(function() {
    str = $(this).val();
    $(this).data('value', str);
    $(this).val(getMaskedValue(str));
  });
```

He is also right that you don't need `.data()`,
you could store the real value in a variable.
It will be good to hide it within a closure.
([See fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/rokt5yfm/))

```
(function() {
  function getMaskedValue(s) {
    var masklen = s.length - 4;
    return s.substr(0, masklen).replace(/./g, '*') + s.substr(masklen);
  }

  var $cc = $('.cc');
  var value = $cc.val();

  $cc
    .val(getMaskedValue(value))
    .focus(function() {
      $(this).val(value);
    })
    .blur(function() {
      value = $(this).val();
      $(this).val(getMaskedValue(value));
    });
})();
```

I also simplified the implementation of computing the masked value,
which should perform better, eliminating array operations.

Answer (score 2):

Leave the original value in `str`. Here's a clean and simple answer that includes re-hide on `blur`:

```
var cc = $('.cc');
var str;
var trailingCharsIntactCount = 4;

function getHiddenValue() {
  str = cc.val();
  return new Array(str.length - trailingCharsIntactCount + 1).join('*') + str.slice(-trailingCharsIntactCount);
}

cc.val(getHiddenValue());
cc.focus(function() { cc.val(str); });
cc.blur(function() { cc.val(getHiddenValue()); });
```